# Не могу отладить Android приложение

Tags: android, android-studio, отладка

Всем привет! Не могу отладить Android приложение. Когда нажимаю на кнопку Debug приложение запускается но при первом же экране зависает
на 5-10 мин, после этого все же запускается в режиме отладки но при этом сильно лагает, тормозит. Это только при отладке а если я просто запускаю приложение все отлично работает. Пробовал сначала запустить приложения а потом "Attach debugger to Android process" но не помогло.

**Проблема**

1. При первом запуске надо ждать около 5-10 минут
2. Приложение сильно тормозит во время отладки не могу нормально
   отладить.

Не могу понять в чем проблема. Что может замедлить отладку?

FYI работаю в довольно большом кампании, проект большой, спросил у разработчиков они тоже не знают. Как они работают без отладки честно говоря не знаю

Пробовал все эти варианты но без результата:
[stackoverflow1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16753939/not-able-to-debug-app-in-android-studio), [stackoverflow2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40233281/android-studio-debugger-taking-too-long-to-start-load), [intellij-support](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544799-Java-slow-performance-or-hangups-when-starting-debugger-and-stepping)

Буду признателен за помощь!

Comment: Ну так оно останавливается в том месте где брейкпойнт. На то и дебаг.

Comment: Проблема в том что нет никаких брейкпоинтов

Comment: Так а дебаггер то что говорит? Приложение остановлено, работает, не отвечает?

Comment: Вариантов может быть тьма. Например, вставки в коде выполняющиеся только в debug версии. В любом случае как минимум логи используйте.

Comment: @woesss обновил вопрос

Comment: возможно просто эмулятор прогружается? просто как вариант, хотя я полагаю памяти хватает

Comment: @Shams А на чем Android проект пишешь?

Comment: Есть и Kotlin и java